# Can a grounding rod be connected to service neutral only?

Tags: grounding

My grounding rod is connected to the service neutral at the weatherhead where it enters the house. Should it not be connected to the ground bar in the 200A breaker panel?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the weatherhead, and inside the service panel?

Comment: If the neutral bond is in place in the panel, it IS connected to the ground bar, just not in the usual way. Not entirely kosher by current practice, but probably functional (to the often limited extent that any driven ground rod is functional) despite that.

Answer (score 2):

The grounding electrode can be connected at the service drop. It's kind of unconventional, but it is fine.

Here is an excellent graphic from Mike Holt. Keep in mind, most areas now disallow connection inside a meter can.

©Mike Holt

[image]

Comment: Huh. My circa 2010 service the bond is in the meter can (as far as I understood, at the explicit behest of the power company, or so my electrician told me.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal, our POCO used to also mandate that the GEC terminates in the meter pan as well as the panel. This practice was discontinued about 15 years ago here.
It's certainly NEC approved, it's just most/many POCOs do not consider the inside of a meter pan "accessible" since we are not allowed to cut tags without approval/consent.